# An Issue with ion-item tag

Tags: html, css, ionic3

I am working on a Login page where the user chooses the country code then enters his phone number.
The two input fields (code, phone number) are in one line together

The Problem I have is that when I use the ion-item it divide the width between the two input fields equally even if I change the width in the .scss file

I have been in this problem for 2 days and can't get it yet.

Here is my .scss file

```
ion-item{
    margin-top:170px;
    width: 100%;
}


.countryCode{
    width:20%;
    margin-right: 3px;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}

.phoneNumber{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 3px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}
```

and here is my HTML file ion item tag

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>

  <ion-input class="countryCode" type="text" [(ngModel)]="countryCode" name="code" (tap)="openCountriescodePage()" placeholder="+">{{countryCode}}</ion-input>
  <ion-input class="phoneNumber" type="text" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber"></ion-input>

</ion-item>

<button margin-top ion-button full color="success" (click)="login()">{{'login' | translate}}</button>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `min-width` and `max-width` it will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using important,

```
ion-item{
    margin-top:170px;
    width: 100%;
}


.countryCode{
    width:20%;
    margin-right: 3px !important;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}

.phoneNumber{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 3px !important;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
}
```

Comment: nothing changed, I used !important before and still can't get what I want